# How to properly deserialize enumerated message types

Tags: rust, serde

I'm building a client that listens to CoinBase messages. I can currently receive messages from a websocket and I need to deserialize them into a number of types. However, the information that I'd like to keep from each object is different.

For example, here's the `Subscriptions` type

`{"type":"subscriptions","channels":[{"name":"ticker","product_ids":["ETH-BTC","ETH-USD","ETH-EUR"]},{"name":"level2","product_ids":["ETH-EUR","ETH-USD"]},{"name":"heartbeat","product_ids":["ETH-USD","ETH-EUR"]}]}`

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "type", content = "channels")]
pub enum CoinbaseMessage {
    #[serde(rename = "subscriptions")]
    Subscriptions(Vec<Channel>),
}
```

I like this because there's no need to store the type or just the field `channels` since once I know the type I know that it's just a vector of Channels.

However, here's a different message with quite a different structure:
`{"type":"ticker","sequence":14882993341,"product_id":"ETH-EUR","price":"1496.94","open_24h":"1517.59","volume_24h":"4485.69558092","low_24h":"1489.56","high_24h":"1547.52","volume_30d":"139511.74143511","best_bid":"1496.92","best_bid_size":"0.32000000","best_ask":"1497.33","best_ask_size":"1.78488479","side":"sell","time":"2023-01-22T02:04:50.378398Z","trade_id":42517165,"last_size":"0.61493625"}`

It does not have any field called `channels` so understandably I can't add it to my enums like this and expect it to work:

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(tag = "type", content = "channels")]
pub enum CoinbaseMessage {
    #[serde(rename = "subscriptions")]
    Subscriptions(Vec<Channel>),
    #[serde(rename = "ticker")]
    Ticker(Ticker)
}
```

In this case there isn't any unpacking I'd like to do at deserialization. I can fix this by remove the `content = "channels"` tag and replacing `Subscriptions(Vec<Channel>)` with `Subscriptions(Channels)`
and define channels as

```
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
pub struct Channels {
    channels: Vec<Channel>
}
```

But I don't love this because all channels is doing is holding a a vector of channels when I'd rather just have the vector of channels.

Is there a way to have both properties I want using Serde? Right now the easiest way seems to just write my own parser. Maybe the standard solution if I still want to stay tied to Serde is to implement my own `Deserializer` but at that point I don't see much of an advantage to using Serde and maybe I should just write my own parser.

Comment: You could also do `Subscriptions { channels: Vec<Channel> }` instead of having a separate type.

Comment: @cdhowie that's a good idea, I forgot you could do that with enums haha. Still new to Rust